# Getting NameError trying to access my tkinter widget in my button command function

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a class for my tkinter GUI and for some reason I can't access the `Entry` widget I created in my button's callback function:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        entry = tk.Entry(master)
        entry.pack()

        self.run = tk.Button(master, text="Run", command=self.run)
        self.run.pack()

    def run(self):
        print('Entry content is:', entry.get())

root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The code throws `NameError: name 'entry' is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's another problem with this code. You overwrite the `self.run` method with the Button. Actually, there's no need to bind that Button to a name.

Comment: @PM2Ring: arrghh, yes... there is a clash between the name of the method, and the attribute.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I do not think you should be editing the OPs code. You made quite a significant change. If there is something wrong with the code then it needs to stay intact so others can see and review. Maybe it should be rolled back and then only edit the text not the code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Not sure what you mean. The thing that was wrong with the OP's code is still there. If there were other wrong things, I don't think they matter. We're a Q&A site, we answer specific questions. We're not Code Review; fixing every tiny problem in the OP's code isn't what we do. I'm planning to use this question as my go-to duplicate target for future questions, so I don't want there to be any irrelevant noise besides the issue the question is asking about.

Comment: @Aran-Fey well There are issues with the OP's code that should have been addressed instead of removing or changing them. I do not think I have ever seen anyone here actually make such changes to someones code without it being rolled back so someone is bound to do it. Besides there is already post about this exact problem where someone names a variable the same as a function.

Comment: Bleh, I just noticed the name clash with `run`... and Willem already updated his answer to address it... what a waste of an *almost* perfectly good duplicate target... Now I have to find and edit another one.........

Comment: @Mike-SMT If there are already posts about this exact problem, then why should we answer it again? It's not the problem the OP asked about, so why shouldn't I remove it? The question is now a useless piece of junk with 2 completely unrelated problems. Again, SO is Q&A, not 2Q&2A.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sure we do answer more specific problems when someone ask a question however is it not better to correct everything we see so the OP does not continue to write code that contains these errors or bad habits? Maybe take a look at this post [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) and read up on some of the resources. It is a common consensus that it is generally not a good idea to edit the OPs code except for very minor fixes.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I don't think it's better, no. We're slowly filling SO with hopelessly broad questions that are only relevant to one person - the OP who asked that question. Nobody else will ever have these two problems. I'd much rather have an SO that's full of *specific* questions; questions that are relevant to a larger audience. The OP can continue to shoot himself in the foot for all I care. They can post another question about that other issue, and *then* we can correct that mistake. There's no reason to do it here, in a question about a completely different problem.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I guess we will just have to agree to disagree. I believe its better to correct all the problems at once rather than let the OP continue to make bad code and have to continue asking question we already know the answer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the `entry` as attribute in the `self`, nor did you access it from `self`. Furthermore you define a `self.run`, as well as a `def run(..)` method, which will result in the fact that the method, for an *instance* will be overwritten. You thus should rename it to something else, for example `_run`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.entry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.entry.pack()

        self._run = tk.Button(master, text="Run", command=self.run)
        self._run.pack()

    def run(self):
        print('Entry content is:', self.entry.get())

root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey: to show the "diff" (and the important parts of the changes).

Comment: I understand *why* you made it bold, I just didn't know it was possible!

Comment: Yea, also noted. Uses the xml syntax <pre><code>, some html wizardy?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem while you are already at it `from tkinter import*` is not very pythonic. But I guess that's the only library I see it nowadays.

Comment: @AntonvBR: indeed, wildcard imports are not very advisable.

Comment: @AntonvBR: correct, you can write code between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` and thus then this allows you to do extra formatting.

Comment: Is there any chance we could remove the thing with the `run` name clash from the question and focus solely on the `self` thing? I was planning to use this question as my go-to duplicate target for these kinds of questions, but if the question has another - completely unrelated - problem then it's worthless as a duplicate target. (See also my discussion with Mike under the question)

Comment: @Aran-Fey: would using two code fragments be an option?

Comment: Sorry, but that wouldn't work for me. I don't want to use a question with 2 unrelated problems as a duplicate target. Think about it this way: If you posted a question like "What's wrong with X?" and someone posted an answer saying "You can fix X like this. Oh and by the way, you can fix Y like that.", that would be pretty bad answer, wouldn't it? The same thing goes for duplicates. The `run` problem is only relevant for this specific OP and nobody else. I don't want to link every future asker with the same X to an answer that talks about an Y that doesn't even exist in their question.